# Bind Arrayadapter to textview android

Tags: android, android-listview

i want to display data from sqlite to textview,here is my code.What i have dont wrong.It is not displaying the data no error but crashes
main class

```
private void loadTextViewData()
{
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.test_list_item, lables);

text.setText(??);                   
}
```

sql class

```
public List<String> getAllLabels(){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }
```

Comment: put your logcat trace..

Comment: Consider using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) and then setting your ArrayAdapter to the ListView : lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter).

Comment: but i dont want a listview

Comment: You want to insert the whole content of your List<String> into a single TextView ?

Comment: no just single data in each textview

Comment: Why do you use an ArrayAdapter then ? These objects are used with AdapterViews such as ListView, GridView, Spinner, ... but not a TextView

Comment: Use a ListView that shows a single TextView for each item, then _listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter)_ will work. See this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) for an example.

Comment: i just want to show a single quote in each screen then scrolling then second quote etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of ArrayAdapter use for example SimpleCursorAdapter (or any subclass of CursorAdapter)